# How to create a notification message on a shiny to show the success or failure of an even

Tags: r, shiny

I have created an app using shiny that allows users to upload pdf documents to Rstudio Connect (these documents also get tagged according to the information in the SelectInput boxes). The app requires the user to upload a single pdf file, then fill in some information then click on the action button "Upload" to get the file uploaded.

Currently the app works well and the files get uploaded however the problem is that the user goes not know if the file has been successfully uploaded or not. They have to logon to Rstudio Connect to view this.

How can I use the showNotification() function or another function to show a message that the file has been successfully uploaded to Rstudio Connect or not?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps in your search. Create a reactive notification that checks if the input from the upload is done (the actionbutton and name can be replaced with the uploadbutton) and afterwards send out a notification.

```
 shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("show", "Show")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$show, {
      showNotification("This is a notification.")
    })
  }
)
```